# Responsive Sass Variables

Tags: sass

So I have created a function to convert px's to em's. The default is to use the a variable `$base-font-size`. So what is the best practice to follow if I want to change that variable based on browser width? Is that possible? If I change the variable will all the places that call the function recalculate?

```
@function em($pixels, $context: $base-font-size) {
  @return ($pixels / $context) * 1em;
}
```

Or would I have to at every place that calls this function, re-call it? Thanks

Comment: You could also consider using Viewport width and height settings which are responsive and change font size according to the viewport width https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would never alter the base font size of the application but rather set values *based off of it* at specific device sizes using media queries.

**As an example:**

```
$base-font-size: 14px;

@function em($pixels, $context: $base-font-size) {
  @return ($pixels / $context) * 1em;
}

* {
  font-size: em(12px);
  @media (min-width: 300px) { 
      font-size: em(16px);
  }
  @media (min-width: 640px) { 
      font-size: em(14px);
  }
  @media (min-width: 980px) { 
      font-size: em(12px);
  }
}
```

**Which would compile as something like:**

```
* {
  font-size: 0.85714286em;
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  * {
    font-size: 1.14285714em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  * {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  * {
    font-size: 1.14285714em;
  }
}
```

Obviously, tailor to your needs.

Comment: But the base font would still be 14px for the media queries, right?

Comment: Yes the base font variable itself never changes.